# How do I trace a graph in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

Can I draw this graph using Inkscape? I am new to this image editor and I have read the guidelines but it still seems hard to do.
Can you please help me to draw an identical graph that also includes the symbols?

Comment: What is your final goal in drawing this graph in Inkscape? Knowing this might help giving a better suited answer. Also a good question shows what you have tried yourself already. Could you please include that in your post?

Comment: Can you draw it manually? Of course. Use the line tool, the bezier curve tool, and the type tool. If you're struggling with any of that, come back to ask specific questions.

Comment: Do you want to draw such graphs from scratch? Are you searching for a function which takes formulas and produces the image or do you have the image and transfer it into svg? Asking for the symbols should be a separate question, imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written in the comments, *it's simpler draw manually such a graph*. The net is plenty of tutorials, and a good guide to start is [Tavmjong Bah](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.php) one, I've found it really useful.

Please note that Inkscape `can` be used to *draw* graphs, but isn't a mathematical *specific* tool (like [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), etc), able to give you an *accurate* plot of the function. Anyway...

As a starting point, you can `import` the image in Inkscape (by dragging it in Inkscape or using File->Import), better if in a separate layer (so later you can hidden it):

[image: original image]

You can [trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28image_tracing%29) the image using Path->Trace Bitmap, tweaking a little and updating the preview until you are satisfied, but usually tracing algorithms creates closed paths and for drawings like this the effect isn't optimal (*it's ugly*!):

[image: image traced with potrace]

A **better solution**, as evidenced by @DA01, is `drawing manually` the graphs. It's a very simple operation which involves just lines and text (using the proper fonts you can have symbols too), there are a lot of tutorials on the net and - not last - Inkscape provides extensions to `plot functions` (see examples [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/12/21/function-plots-inkscape/), [there](http://7900av.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/inkscape-function-plotter-examples/), ...). You can lock the layer with the original bitmap, add a new layer and drawing on it (perhaps using guidelines, if it helps):

[image: manual drawing using guidelines]

The result is a manual drawing that *seems* like your graph:

[image: manual drawing cleaned]

The **best way** is reading manuals, following tutorials and trying by yourself: graphs like these are goals which everyone can achieve (perhaps with a more specific tool).

Comment: I like your answer. Are the greek letters available as text in Inkscape?

Comment: @John The availability of the letters depends simply from the availability in the font used. In my example I was on a Windows machine and I've used tahoma.ttf selecting the characters with charmap (in Linux you can use [other tools](http://fsymbols.com/character-maps/linux/)). Alternatively, in Inkscape you can insert directly an [unicode value](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) by pressing Ctrl-U in text tool (see [here](http://inkscape.org/doc/tips/tutorial-tips.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Based on my limited experience, drawing these curves is a pain, and anyone who knows their mathematical functions can see it's a crude approximation. On the other hand, many modern plotting packages can export to vector based formats, either  SVG  or PDF, which Inkscape can easily import. So I disagree with the above answer, I think creating the plot and saving it as SVG is by far the easiest, prettiest and mosts elegant solution.

The python/based [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net) can export plots to SVG. 
It is at the base of it a command-line tool (although the IPython [Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) interface is very nice and handy), but for simple plots, it is very easy to use.

```
from pylab import *
x = linspace(-10, 1-, 1000)  # Start, stop, number of steps
y = sin(x)
plot(x, y)
```

In the interactive plot window that comes up, one can choose to save the figure as .svg, and then easily imported to Inkscape and styled as you want to.

Easiest way to get it to run fast is to install the Anaconda scientific python distribution. It installs in a single directory, so uninstalling is just a matter of removing that directory.

Also [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info) can export to svg. There is a demo/tutorial [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_svg_4.6/). Gnuplot is probably as good as Matplotlib for your purpose, it's just that as a long time Python lover, I'm partial to Python-based plotting tools.

Octave can export to at least PDF, don't know about SVG.